# Facebook Developer Account Verify

Tags: facebook, admin

I created a new Facebook account and verified it with my cell phone. I even see "Your mobile phone has been successfully verified." in https://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php address.

So, everything seems perfect.

Then, I became Facebook friends with my friend (he is also verified and already created an Application). We are trying to add ME as an ADMIN for this Facebook Application from HIS account.

Even though both are completely verified by phone, HE canNOT add me as ADMIN for that application. He is getting

Only verified developers can be added as listed developers of this application. Read http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17580 for details.

message all the time.

We waited more than an hour just in case the Facebook system did not recognize my new verification.

In fact, I even tried removing the phone number and get verified again.

None of above did work and still getting the message which does not allow me to become an Admin of the application.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to login to developer.facebook.com?? Because you are only a facebook user, try that and after that ask your friend to add you as a admin.

Comment: Yes I did.. But I noticed that, when I tried to create a new App it says:
You can no longer create apps because our systems indicated that your account may not be authentic. Facebook requires users to provide their real first and last names, and fake accounts are a violation of our Statement of Rights and Responsibilities (SRR 4.1), even when used to host or test apps. Also note that maintaining multiple accounts, even if they are authentic, is also prohibited. If you would like to create a test user to test app functionality, you can do so here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Comment: Nothing in my account is incorrect or fake.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the error message - you can appeal the restriction if you believe it's incorrect

Comment: I followed and send a message to the Facebook personnel. Hopefully, they'll tell me something useful.

Comment: @ErayAcar Hey r u able to solve this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not yet.

Comment: @Eray Acar: Still? (I’m having the same problem!)

Comment: No luck unfortunately. We had to abandon the issue in my company.

Comment: @Eray Acar: I managed to have eMail contact to somebody at Facebook. I’m awaiting an investigation of the issue now.

Comment: Please share the info when you get an answer. Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same problem, however I have no issues creating my own new apps. But the company I am now working for say that they cannot add my Facebook ID to their apps because it says my account has not been verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, facebook itself does not accept my account and thinks it is duplicate account. And in order to make them believe the Facebook team want me to provide these below:

> Our systems indicated that your account may not be authentic based on
>   a variety of factors. If you believe you are being prevented from
>   creating apps by mistake, please reply to this email with a digital
>   image of your government-issued identification. Make sure the
>   identification you provide meets all of the following requirements:
>
> - Must be government-issued (e.g. passport, driver's license)
> - Must be in color
> - Must clearly show your full name, date of birth, and photo
>
> If possible, please save this file in JPEG image format.

I dont know why they are making such a huge problem.

Comment: It's probably because you have multiple accounts, or an account in a fake name, etc. This is against Facebook policy

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of people having all kinds of problems with the developer section of Facebook.com

One resolution seems to be to log out of both accounts and log back in again.

Comment: Thank your for your comment. But, I've also tried that several times and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used phone number to login my account and hadn't any email attached. after adding email as a primary contact I was able to verify my developer account.