# How can I get an APP ID so I can access the Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, app-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need an appId for a XFBML version of the Facebook Like button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574443/do-i-need-an-appid-for-a-xfbml-version-of-the-facebook-like-button)

I would like to use the Facebook JavaScript SDK to sense when the Like button on my page is clicked so I can do other things on my own page at that time.  But I apparently need an App ID and it's not clear how I get one of these.  I submitted a cell phone number so Facebook could send me a secret number to authenticate me, but when I submitted  that number I just got dropped into the Facebook Developers Group, which didn't seem to be any help getting an App ID.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you will get that on Facebook-developer portal.All you need to create an App there and once it is created you will be given an App-ID.i guess this might help you [how-to-get-a-facebook-app-id](http://rieglerova.net/how-to-get-a-facebook-app-id/)

Comment: You don't need an appId for a send button.
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11319154/121725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and create a new app.

The app Id will be visible once created.

Comment: I went to the link above and filled out the form, but I got the message: "You can no longer create apps because our systems indicated that your account may not be authentic."  I don't know how they came to that conclusion!  And that was after they authenticated me by texting a secret code to my cell phone, which I entered back correctly. What a horrible developers platform Facebook has!  The software lets something that should be so simple to do turn into a nightmare,  with no human oversight anywhere!   Thanks for any help through this.  Steve

Comment: Seems like others have had your issue to. You will need to contact Facebook Support (good luck) and see if it can be rectified. Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874654/facebook-developer-account-verify