# JavaScript SDK - App ID

Tags: button, sdk, facebook-social-plugins, app-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get an APP ID so I can access the Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753465/how-can-i-get-an-app-id-so-i-can-access-the-facebook-javascript-sdk)

No 'send button' without JavaScript SDK. But the JavaScript SDK requires that you register your website with Facebook to get an App ID.

I understood finally I got this App ID by starting making an app (?). But I was not allowed. Account verified, send copie passport... etc Hopefully this will come to an end and will be OK

But still wondering if this will be indeed the easiest way to make just a 'send button'... (which asks JavaScript SDK)

Thanks 
Bert

Comment: In theory it is optional: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/